# Change data from UI with data binding

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

My understanding about data binding in Windows 10 programming is GUI can reflects the data change and also can manipulate the data. Am I wrong here?

I have list of customized data defined in App.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Screen> screens;
```

The structure of Screen is like

```
public class Screen : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set 
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChange("Name")
            } 
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled { /* same as Name*/ }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChange(this, new PropertyChangeEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

In one of my page, let's say page1, I define a listbox in xaml

```
<ListBox Name="screenListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}">
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}">
        <DataTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And I bind the listbox to the screens list in App

```
screenListBox.ItemsSource = App.screens
```

In the constructor of page1, I instantiate 2 screens

```
App.screens = new ObservableCollection<Screen>() { /*some initial list*/ };
```

There is another page, let's say page2, click a button navigate from page1 to page2, since screens is in App and public static. So in page2 I have access to them.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), null);
```

The problem is after I make some changes via GUI on page1, they doesn't reflect back to the screens list in App. An example is if I change the name of the first item in the list on page1 then set a break point before page switching, I can see the screens list is not changed. I also try to use a checkbox tapped handler and manually update the isEnable property. But I can't seem to find the checkbox's corresponding index in the list.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**Edit:** Make screen inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged.

**Edit:** Use ObservableCollection instead of List

**Edit:** Can't figure out the index of a tapped checkbox in its event handler

Comment: Your Screen class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I implement INotifyPropertyChanged for screen class, still the same result.

Comment: Bind not Bond I get English is probably a second language

Comment: Try not make screens static and pass it in the ctor

Comment: Also, your Enabled binding should be `TwoWay`.

Comment: You also should be using an ObservableCollection instead of a List.  An observable collection will notify the UI the list has changed.  (ie new item, or deleted item)

Comment: @KenTucker Sorry I did use ObservableCollection but forgot to update the question.

Comment: @JustinXL What do you mean by TwoWay?

Comment: @Frisbee I did try to pass some data from this.Frame.Navigate, but it did not work, that was why I change it to static collection in App. I think the problem is not about static storage, since I set a breakpoint in the click handler, the data doesn't get changed even it does.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the reply. I think my problem is the change in GUI doesn't reflect into data, not the other way around. I think ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged are all for reflecting changes in data to GUI.

Comment: Are you setting App.screens to a new observable collection after the page was displayed?  this can use the binding to not see the update.  I always clear the items from a list and add new items to list to prevent binding issues

Comment: I initiate App.screens right after InitializeComponent call in page1, then never reassign again. I start to think if I should use other controls instead of  listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all others' suggestions are helpful. And @Justin XL has pointed out the point how you can make it reflect to backend object/collection.

Make the binding Twoway. There are two scenarios:

1. If you only want to reflect the change to the properties like Name and Enabled. Just make the following change:

   ```
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   ```
2. If you want to reflect to the collection like add/delete actions, use a customized binding to the itemssource property as below:

   ```
   Binding sbinding = new Binding();
   sbinding.Source = App.screens;
   sbinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
   screenListBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, sbinding);
   ```

I've tested your scenarios on my end, and it works very well.

Comment: I can't believe this problem took me 3 days to solve and the solution was surprisingly simple. Thank you @Alan Yao.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. :)